# Do single bit errors during raid 5 rebuild currpt the entire array?

Tags: raid, rebuild

Does a single bit error during a raid 5 rebuild break the entire array? if so, why? If a single block of data was corrupted/misread during the rebuild, would that not simply result in one block of corrupt data on the newly rebuilt drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RAID5 maintains parity bits on one drive, a one bit error would affect only that particular bit on the other drives. So, all other data is safe.

Comment: Should i then avoid encryption on a raid 5 array since loosing any data on an encrypted volume will render the data useless? Also, does this apply both for software raid and hardware? thanks.

Comment: Encryption works with specific size blocks, and only the block containing the invalid bit will be corrupt if a single bit is corrupt. And yes, the same applies for both software and hardware RAID.

Comment: But the loss of one block in an encrypted volume would result in the loss of the entire volume would it not?